# Paralel RadixSort of numbers

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm learning parallel programming and I'm wondering how i can most effectively parallel [*Radix sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).
I've got and idea that before radix ill sort numbers by the count of digits and than ill send them to `radixSort` algorithm and connect sorted arrays by the digits. But i don't think its the best was to sort this algorithm. Here's code that i want to change to parallel.

````
import time


def countingSort(array, place):
    size = len(array)
    output = [0] * size
    count = [0] * 10

    # Calculate count of elements
    for i in range(0, size):
        index = array[i] // place
        count[index % 10] += 1

    # Calculate cumulative count
    for i in range(1, 10):
        count[i] += count[i - 1]

    # Place the elements in sorted order
    i = size - 1
    while i >= 0:
        index = array[i] // place
        output[count[index % 10] - 1] = array[i]
        count[index % 10] -= 1
        i -= 1

    for i in range(0, size):
        array[i] = output[i]


# Main function to implement radix sort
def radixSort(array):
    # Get maximum element
    max_element = max(array)

    # Apply counting sort to sort elements based on place value.
    place = 1
    while max_element // place > 0:
        countingSort(array, place)
        place *= 10
    return array


start_time = time.time()
data = [23950, 55149, 6262, 80988, 61698, 46356, 44771, 86534, 17326, 45511, 3214, 90191, 15316, 18330, 60983, 70108, 37905, 94157]
data = radixSort(data)
end_time = time.time()
print("Time was", round(end_time - start_time, 3), "sekúnd.")
print(data)```
````

Comment: This is not simple, especially in Python. If your goal is to implement a fast sorting algorithm, then this is a not a good idea to do that because the overhead of CPython is huge compared to the benefit of the parallelization. In this case, consider using Numpy which is vectorized (optimized in C). The radix sort is split in two parts: building an histogram and then reordering numbers based on the histogram.

Comment: The histogram part is known to be hard to parallelise. One solution is to use atomics but they are not available in Python. Another solution is to compute N histograms and then merge them. This is cumbersome to do in Python because of the lack of simple shared memory access. Python is not great for parallel computing. It just provide the basics for embarrassingly parallel computations but not much more (there are ways to communicate between processes but they are very inefficient and and pretty cumbersome to use).

Answer (score 0):

Two parts of the `countingSort` you're doing can theoretically be parallelized, though I'm not sure how practical it is to do it in Python, since I'm not aware of an easy to use approach to sharing data between processes without excessive synchronization overheads.

First, you could have separate processes counting digits in different parts of the input list. Each would have their own count, separate from the other processes, so all the counting could happen in parallel.

Then after the counting is done, you'd do some centralized math to combine the separate counts. This is the equivalent to the cumulative count step in the regular algorithm, but you'd accumulate across the counts of the separate processes.

Finally, each process could put its elements into the right places into the shared output list. Since each process would only modify the parts of the output list where their own values get placed, the processes wouldn't step on each other's toes, if you had the right kind of shared data structure.

Here's a very small example of how that would work for two processes, hand waving most of the actual code, just showing the data:

```
# first half  <---------------->
input_data = [60, 36, 65, 61, 26, 89, 69, 81, 90, 83]
# second half                     <---------------->

digit = 1

# count first half of input in one process
first_half_count = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
# count the second half in another process
second_half_count = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]

# accumulate across the two counts
first_half_count = [1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8]
second_half_count = [2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10]

# put values into the output, with each process using its own updated count
#         v       v           v   v   v    inserted by the first process 
output = [60, 90, 61, 81, 83, 65, 36, 26, 89, 69]
#             ^       ^   ^               ^   ^ and by the second process
```

Like I said at the top, I'm not sure how to efficiently implement the parallel steps in Python, because there aren't any easy to use data structures that can be accessed by multiple processes in parallel without a lot of overhead that we don't need for this algorithm.